# how to use materialize CSS to make the form responsive to phones as it opens from an app

Tags: html, css, materialize

I created a form that it is connected to my google Doc but the problem the form is responsive to phone screen as it I want it to be. please check the attached picture
[this how it looks in my phone browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT98u.jpg)

I want it to full screen like it is opened from an app. I have used materialize CSS.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title> creat PDF </title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Your name" id="name" type="text" class="validate">
                <label class="active" for="name">First Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Your name" id="id" type="text" class="validate">
                <label class="active" for="id">Your Id</label>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Your name" id="dep" type="text" class="validate">
                <label class="active" for="dep">Your Department</label>
            </div>
        </div>


        <button id="btn" onclick="waitingMessage()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"
            name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
        <div id="msg">
            <div>

            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

            <?!=include('js');?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you solved it? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [grid](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) section of materialize css it is the most important section of any css framework.

Here is a solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title> creat PDF </title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m6 offset-m3 s12 ">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input placeholder="Your name" id="name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label class="active" for="name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input placeholder="Your name" id="id" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label class="active" for="id">Your Id</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input placeholder="Your name" id="dep" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label class="active" for="dep">Your Department</label>
                    </div>
                    <button id="btn" onclick="waitingMessage()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"
                        name="action">Submit
                        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

            </div>
            <div id="msg">
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <?!=include('js');?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but still I have to zoom my browser to be able to input text in the form. which makes it an unfriendly form. but your adding made the form in the center in the browser which is good.

Comment: @Nasaf With my code I don't need to zoom at my phone to see the form correct. Try with other browser and check if you have activate the browser option "Show the page as desktop" something like that. This option makes the browser to ignore the "viewport" at metatag

Comment: You saved my life thank you.